# How can I watch an ngModel value before it's valid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-ngmodel, angular-directive

I have a password field with a passwordStrengthMeter element directive beside it. I'd like the passwordStrengthMeter to observe changes to the password field and update in real time -- not just on blur or when the password field's model passes validation.

I'm using Angular validation on the password field, I'm finding that my directive cannot observe changes to the password field until the password field is valid. I want password validation to remain intact, but I also want realtime strength indication. How can I make this work? Here is what I have so far...

HTML:

```
<input class="control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="account.password"
       ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="15" ng-pattern="VALIDATION_PATTERNS.passwordStrength" required ng-focused />
<password-strength-meter password-field="account.password"></password-strength-meter>
```

And the directive:

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('passwordStrengthMeter', function() {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="password-strength-meter"></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // Map scores to CSS classes.
            var scoreClasses = {
                0: 'blank',
                1: 'weak',
                2: 'moderate',
                3: 'strong',
                4: 'very-strong'
            };

            var scorer = function() {
                // Get password value.
                var password = scope.$eval(attrs.passwordField);

                // Calculate a score.
                // TODO Replace this with an actual calculation.
                return password.length;
            }
            scope.$watch(scorer, function(score) {
                // Remove any score classes for the element.
                for (var i in scoreClasses) {
                    element.removeClass(scoreClasses[i]);
                }

                // Set class based on score.
                element.addClass(scoreClasses[score]);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that setting

```
ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"
```

on the password input field works around the issue.

If anyone has an alternative or better solution, feel free to post.

Comment: [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions), for future reference.